# How would I add an element based on priority to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, compare, priority-queue

I have to add some elements to a PriorityQueue ADP in java. I need to add them based on priority so that the array is ordered. I wanted to iterate through the elements in the array and compare them to the element i want to add. If its larger, I would add it before, if not, i would move on. If its the same, i would add it after. I have an idea of what to do but am unsure how to implement the compare described in the code below

```
while(array != null){
    for(int i = 0; i<array.size; i++){  
        if("element to add > element already in array"){

            //add the element before 
            //index and shift other elements back

            for( int i = array.size; i > index; i--){
                array[i] = array[i-1];
            }
            array[index] = elementToAdd
            array_size++;

        if("element to add > element already in array"){

            //add the element after index and shift other elements back

            for(int i = array.size; i > index+1; i--){
                array[i] = array[i-1];
            }
            array[index+1] = elementToAdd
            array_size++;
            }
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What type does your array have? Do you wonder about using Comparators, or the Comparable interface?

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica Its an object array, and im trying to use the .compareTo function for elements of the array

Comment: Objects of what type? And well, it sounds like you should research the keywords I mentioned: Comparable and Comparator.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Bracing is off, so it's hard to say what you're really trying to do. And the condition for both `if` statements is `if("element to add > element already in array")`. I *think* you're trying to insert into a sorted list, but your title says something about a PriorityQueue. Are you trying to implement a simple priority queue in an array?